# Membership provider stopped working on using Membership Provider in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, membership-provider

I have a production ASP.Net MVC application that has been using the membership service.  It has worked fine, up until today.  Nothing has changed on the server, but I now have this error:

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException:
The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.
```

I checked the asp_schemaversions table, and it looks fine.  Please any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem by rebooting the server.  Rather, I should say I fixed the symptom.  I would like to find out if anyone else has encountered this problem before, since rebooting the server every time it crops up doesn't seem to be the proper fix.

Comment: FYI, http://robmzd.blogspot.com/2010/10/sqlmembershipprovider-requires-database.html